# Can't read environment variables from a Grunt server-run Node + AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, environment-variables

I've created an app on AngularJS and Firebase. I decided to store the Firebase credentials as environment variables. I am on Ubuntu, and I run the development server using Grunt.

I tried creating a `.bashrc` file to store the environment variables as shown below (with the values inserted between the quotes).

```
export APIKEY=""
export AUTH_DOMAIN=""
export DATABASE_URL=""
export STORAGE_BUCKET=""
export MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=""
```

I then have a `config.js` file that uses these variables to configure Firebase.

```
var config = {
    apiKey: process.env.APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

However, I think Grunt does not pick up these values, because whether I run the Grunt server or run the app using `node server.js`, it doesn't find a value for these variables. I also tried creating the variables from the command line first, like so (with the value inserted between the quotes).

```
$ export APIKEY=""
```

Regardless, my app is unable to see the environment variables. It delivers this error in the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined at config.js:2
```

The app runs fine when I insert the values directly into the `config.js` file. I tried a variety of options for configuring variables in Ubuntu, and none seem to be working.

**Edit:**
*It also might be worth noting that Heroku also does not recognize the variables, though I have registered them with Heroku, and it delivers the same error (`process is not defined`). Could it be something with Angular?*

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a file `env.js` that contains your credentials and require in your `config.js` file. You can ignore the file from `Git`.

**env.js**

```
module.exports = {
  APIKEY: "your-api-key",
  AUTH_DOMAIN: "your-auth-domain",
  DATABASE_URL: "your-database-URL",
  STORAGE_BUCKET: "your-storage-bucket",
  MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: "your-messaging-sender-id"
}
```

**.gitignore**

```
env.js
```

**config.js**

```
var keys = require('env');

var config = {
  apiKey: keys.APIKEY,
  authDomain: keys.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: keys.DATABASE_URL,
  storageBucket: keys.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: keys.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I usually use this methodology to store config information. However, this time I wanted to also make this particular app easily deployed to Heroku, which typically uses environment variables, since this type of file would be stored locally and not be pushed to git. Is there any way to use environment variables successfully within my app? Heroku is also failing to recognize them.

Comment: Since it's a frontend app, you'd need to bundle the credentials with the other javascript files, and deploy the bundle file to heroku, that's how I do it using `gulp`.